# How do you wrap text to the next line in a material UI select/menu item component? (CSS issue)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I'm trying to show a school's cancelled classes in a select menu.  It's arranged by day:
[image: Desktop view looks correct]

However, my menu just cuts off the overflow text when at a mobile resolution in developer tools.
[image]
The thermodynamics class is cut off.

I'm using material ui's select menu with react. [Material UI Select documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/) I'm also using the [menu item](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/). I want to have classes listed overflow onto the next line. The  is where I show the classes per day.

This is the code (it's just an example, and it doesn't run):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label" > Filter classes by day</InputLabel>
     
      <Select
        labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
        id="demo-controlled-open-select"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onOpen={handleOpen}
          defaultValue={subjectFilter}
          onChange={handleChangeSubject}
        className="styleSelect"

        >
         {item.SUBJECT === 'OPEN_LEARNING' && 
               <ul className ="stylingList">
               {(state.subjects) && state.subjects.filter(item => 
               (item.SUBJECT === 'OPEN_LEARNING')).map(item => 
                 <li className ="stList">
                   {item.CLASS_FULL}
                 </li>
                 )}
                 </ul>
              }
            </MenuItem>
            //this is just one day.  I do this for all the days.
          ) )
        }
     
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

I don't have styles on the classes listed. I just made class names to customize the areas later if needed.  I just changed the text color. Thanks. I tried overflow-wrap: break-word; on the li class (stList), but it didn't make the words go to the next line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Override the wrapping style of the Menu Item:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    whiteSpace: "unset",
    wordBreak: "break-all"
  }
}));
//...
const YourComponent =(props)=>{
    const classes = useStyles();
    //...
    <MenuItem  classes={{ root: classes.root }}>
}
```

**NL;PR:** By default, the menu item style `whiteSpace: 'nowrap'` prevents the other wraps to apply. You can inspect how the suggested changes work in this [pastebin](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-pw2gv?file=/demo.js).

Now, your select's menu items will go:

From this:
[image]  to this: [image].

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working perfectly now.  I feel a bit silly for not catching that.

Comment: Don't be, it took me a solid hour to figure it out, =P.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListItem` instead of `MenuItem`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel id="demo-controlled-open-select-label" > Filter classes by day</InputLabel>
       
  <Select
    labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
    id="demo-controlled-open-select"
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    onOpen={handleOpen}
      defaultValue={subjectFilter}
      onChange={handleChangeSubject}
    className="styleSelect"

    >
     {item.SUBJECT === 'OPEN_LEARNING' && 
           <ul className ="stylingList">
           {(state.subjects) && state.subjects.filter(item => 
           (item.SUBJECT === 'OPEN_LEARNING')).map(item => 
             <li className ="stList">
               {item.CLASS_FULL}
             </li>
             )}
             </ul>
          }
        </ListItem>
        //this is just one day.  I do this for all the days.
      ) )
    }

  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used `Typography` with `noWrap` prop in order to wrap the text inside `MenuItem`.

It should be like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  menuItem: {
    display: 'block',
  },
});

const MenuItemWithCaption ({ value, primaryText, secondaryText }) => {
 const classes = useStyles();

 return ( 
  <MenuItem value={value} className={classes.menuItem}>
   <Typography variant="body2" noWrap>
     {primaryText}
   </Typography>
   <Typography variant="caption" noWrap>
     {secondaryText}
   </Typography>
  </MenuItem>
 )
}
```